# Displaying JSON as nested table in Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, web-deployment, jstree

I have a JSON object and I want to display it in the form of a table in Node.js. The table should have nested rows depending on the existence of nested records in the JSON object. I considered jstree plugin but it will be difficult to convert JSON to the JSON array needed by it. Can anyone please suggest me a better option? Any plugin or snippet that could give me a direction?

Answer (score 0):

There is a third party plugin to jstree called jstree-grid:
https://github.com/deitch/jstree-grid

As for converting the JSON - you can use `core.data` as a function and convert the format on the client side.

Answer (score -1):

Try this [jsonastable](https://github.com/freddi301/jsonastable)

Ot is a clone of json2table but MIT licensed.

You can include it in your site.